# webtends - How to test its working

Tags: ios, webtrends

I have been given a webtrends DCSID number that is liked with my clients webtrends account.

However I have not been given access to the clients account, so I have no way of verifying if the reporting is working.

Is there a way to verify if it is working, e.g. setting up a trial account to test on?

The target is an iPhone app

Answer (score 2):

You can also download an HTTP monitoring tool that will show you everything that is sent to Webtrends when the tag fires. It won't show you what the reports will look like, but testing the tag should really be the first step in any tagging implementation. If the tagging doesn't work as expected, the reports won't work either. :)

**Standalone tools:** [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (free) or HttpWatch (basic or paid). **Firefox Add-on:** HTTPfox (free).

To test how the tag fires from an iPhone, you will need to either use a User Agent switcher/spoofer in your desktop browser, or use an actual iPhone and monitor the traffic using Fiddler—[here are instructions](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html). Once you install one of these, look for the hits to *http(s)://statse.webtrendslive.com/[the client's DCSID]/dcs.gif?etcetera*

Answer (score 1):

You can go to https://tagbuilder.webtrends.com and generate the needed files for tracking, e.g. an empty html page and the javascript. If possible, upload both to a test webspace and access the page. Type into the addressbar

```
javascript:dcsDebug();
```

and a small popup will appear. You will now see all informations collected by the javascript and what would be send to the SDC server.

If needed, ask your customer to send you the logfiles of the SDC and compare the logs with your activity.